# Mysql REGEXP 'o' OR 'aw'

Tags: mysql, regex, match

I'm trying to do a friend search app.
So to do that I'm using regular expressions like:

```
SELECT ... 
 WHERE firstname REGEXP $firstname
```

And the $firstname variable is a string - for example:

```
(ch|k)ris
```

But for some reason it does not work. maybe the ( | ) doesn't work in MySQL?

What can I use instead of that operator to do the same thing?

Comment: It aught to work, as long as '$firstname' is treated as a 'quoted' string - there are similar examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PHP modify your line to this:

```
$query = "SELECT ... FROM users WHERE id NOT IN($alreadyfriend) AND firstname REGEXP '$firstname'"; //notice the single quotes
```